# How to use conditional attribute in POM

Tags: java, spring, maven

I needed to pass the selected Maven profile to Spring so that the profile info can be used while running the regression tests using Surefire plugin by adding the `argLine` attribute below. The selected profile is passed as:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <argLine>-Dspring.profiles.active=@{spring.profiles.active} @{argLine}</argLine>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

And then I have to run the test as `mvn clean test -Pdev` (or other env name) all the time. Is there a way I can add a condition that when `-P<env name>` part is not provided, **ignore/skip** `argLine` attribute?

Something like if @{spring.profiles.active}= null then do not include this attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try a property `<argLine>@{argLine}</argLine>` in the `dev` profile (or other env name) and use it in `<argLine>`:

```
<argLine>-Dspring.profiles.active=@{spring.profiles.active} ${argLine}</argLine>
```